# PHP Cli - json encode an array and pass to STDIN

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Im trying to do json encode via the CLI, I can get json decode. It is important to pass via STDIN as I need to perform further actions on the data encoded but im starting to wonder is this possible to do in a one liner

So far I have tried:

```
echo -n '<?php array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5); ?>' | php -r "echo json_encode(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));"
```

and

```
php -r '<?php array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5); ?>' | php -r "echo json_encode(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

`php -r "echo json_encode( array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5) );"`

Which resulted in the following in PHP 7.1.8 cli:

`{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}`